# Nested forEach to retrieve subcollection from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use nested foreach to retrieve multiple subcollections to add to a list:

```
List<Widget> TaskList() {
    List<Widget> lines = [];
    firestoreInstance.collection("tasks").where("type", isEqualTo: "urgent").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
            firestoreInstance.collection("tasks").document(result.documentID).collection("todo").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
                    lines.add(Row(
                    children: <Widget> [
                    Expanded(flex: 7, child: Text("test", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))), Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("test", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))), Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text("test", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), textAlign: TextAlign.right)), ], ));
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return lines;
}
```

The above code can run but the list is blank. I imagine it has something to do with waiting for the queries to complete, because if I replace the forEach by simple for-loop without accessing Firebase, it works (lines added to the list). I know I have to somehow use Future. But I cannot really work out the syntax for this nested foreach scenario.

Grateful for any help or pointers to useful examples.

Comment: make you method async and usr futurebuilder to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async` and `await`:

```
  Future<List<Widget>> TaskList() async {
    List<Widget> lines = [];
    QuerySnapshot result = await firestoreInstance
        .collection("tasks")
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "urgent")
        .getDocuments();
    for (var res in result.documents) {
      QuerySnapshot todoResult = await firestoreInstance
          .collection("tasks")
          .document(res.documentID)
          .collection("todo")
          .getDocuments();
      for (var todoRes in todoResult.documents) {
        lines.add(Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 7, child: Text("test", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
            Expanded(
                flex: 1, child: Text("test", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
            Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Text("test",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
          ],
        ));
      }
    }
    return lines;
  }
}
```

This way the list will not be filled unless both queries are finished. If you are going to use this `future` method inside the `build` method, then do the following:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> TaskList() async {
    QuerySnapshot todoResult;
    QuerySnapshot result = await firestoreInstance
        .collection("tasks")
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "urgent")
        .getDocuments();
    for (var res in result.documents) {
       todoResult = await firestoreInstance
          .collection("tasks")
          .document(res.documentID)
          .collection("todo")
          .getDocuments();
    }
    return todoResult;
  }
```

And use the above function inside `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I didn't follow exactly but got it working by understanding your concept. I am using two FutureBuilder (each with a Future). The first FutureBuilder calls the TaskList() function in a for-loop for each member of the retrieved results. Using the documentID received, the other FutureBuilder retrieves the subcollection. Kind of messy but it works. Working to see if I can simplify it further.